# Inferential statistics for multiple classes / groups

Tags: sampling, inference, descriptive-statistics

I have data regarding calls to a company. Only a small proportion of calls are classified into about a hundred different categories by a group of humans. The volume of calls is in the range of hundreds of thousands and only a few thousand calls are classified. I would like to estimate the proportions of each class in the population of calls using inferential statistics.

I have read a lot about inferential statistics but it seems like all the tutorials out there are about estimating the mean from sampling distributions, but there are only 2 classes - success or fail.

I cannot find anything to help estimate the proportions with more than 2 classes. Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you would need to fit a [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) distribution (generalisation of binomial distribution for more than 2 classes), whose parameter is a vector of probabilities $\pi= (\pi_1, ..., \pi_k)$ where $k$ is the number of different classes. An easy way to estimate these probabilities is to comupte the different proportions of calls in the different categories among all the calls which are already classified(these proportions actually give the maximum likelihood estimator of $\pi$). You can then give confidence interavals, make tests, etc.

If you have explanatory variables you would like to use to estimate proportions, then you can go for a mulitnomial (or polytomous) logistic regression.